# cannot reslove symbol <manifest>"@xml/filepaths" </manifest>in android studio while scanning capture image an retrieve ocr data?

Tags: javascript, android

It cannot find symbol file path getting app crash while scanning capture image for getting OCR:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: how about adding `xml/filepaths.xml` to your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you must not have the file `xml/filepaths.xml` created in your project or it is in the incorrect location. Please make sure it is created and in the correct place and then rebuild your project and the error should go away.